# Flutter: Request is taking too long to process

Tags: json, flutter, request

I am running my application in development (`debug`) mode on local machine so I'm not sure how much this affects network requests. The target device where the app is running is Android emulator. I have an endpoint which fetches some data, this data can be quite large, it's a large-ish JSON that gets parsed into data structure (class) in my application code.

I am experiencing a problem where sometimes these requests time out (my timeout is set at 30s) even though the actual response is less than 5s. I am attaching a screenshot from dev tools where you can see that the duration of the request is 25 seconds which is just too much. I think time to first byte (TTFB) is the actual time before it starts receiving the data, so the server code is not slow. I don't understand how the "end" time is calculated though.

My internet connection (download) is about 50-70Mbit/s (ADSL).

Screenshot:

[image: Flutter dev tools]

What do you think could be the cause for such a long duration of request to be completed? Could it be the size of payload? Or does the framework (Flutter) take a long time to process the response?

I'm using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)² http client to make my requests so not sure if that plays any role. I tried optimising the path where I'm converting JSON response payload into data objects (classes) stored in memory¹ but that doesn't seem to help. I don't think I'm using any weird code pattern³ as all of the other parts of my app are performant.

Unfortunately I can't easily reproduce the situation of what the screenshot is displaying but when I tried doing it, the payload size was over 1MB and in that scenario I believe it could be over 2MB which is pretty large for JSON.

#### `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-CZ)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/user/fvm/versions/2.8.1
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (6 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM A505FN (mobile) • XXXXXXX • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.99

• No issues found!
```

---

¹ I receive list of objects in the JSON response. These objects have nested object lists. One of the lists are GPS coordinates that form a path so there can be lot of them. However I need just one list of coordinates from the list of objects so I just dropped the other ones before converting them to my data structures so it basically cuts down 90% of the previous unoptimized size.

² Version `4.0.0`

³ It's a regular Flutter app where all widgets come from `material.dart` module. The network calls are triggered outside of UI by usage of BLoC pattern (via `flutter_bloc` lib). Each API call has its own event belonging to some BLoC.
The actual API call is performed by a instance of wrapper class that contains an instance of `dio` client and passes the result to relevant BLoC. The instances of wrapper classes and `dio` instances are created via dependency injection. Wrapper classes are singletons, `dio` instances are created once for each of these wrapper classes. The creation of these classes happens before the `runApp`.

Comment: which version of dio are you using?, testing on web, emulator or on real device?, In which mode debug, release or profile?, your internet connection speed?, your flutter doctor -v report?, your coding flow or technique? mention all these above

Comment: I updated my question with the information.

Comment: Hello were you to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I no longer work with Flutter but I'd be interested to know what was the cause anyway.